BackgroundFetch Task Not Triggering Automatically in iOS and Android with Expo and Notifee
I'm working on an Expo project where I'm trying to set up a background fetch task using expo-task-manager and expo-background-fetch to trigger a local notification using @notifee/react-native. The task registers correctly, and it works when triggered manually through tools like Instruments on macOS. However, TaskManager.defineTask does not seem to trigger automatically under normal conditions on iOS
Here's my setup:
Expo SDK Version: 51
Libraries:
expo-task-manager
expo-background-fetch
@notifee/react-native
import { Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Text, View } from "@/components/Themed";
import notifee from "@notifee/react-native";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";
import * as BackgroundFetch from "expo-background-fetch";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK = "background-fetch-task";

TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, async () => {
  try {
    console.log("Background fetch task is running");
    await sendNotification();
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.NewData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in background fetch task:", error);
    return BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchResult.Failed;
  }
});

export async function sendNotification() {
  await notifee.requestPermission();

  const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
    id: "default",
    name: "Default Channel",
  });

  await notifee.displayNotification({
    title: "Welcome to the App Of Heist",
    body: "Main body content of the notification",
    android: {
      channelId,
      smallIcon: "name-of-a-small-icon",
      pressAction: {
        id: "default",
      },
    },
  });
}

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const registerBackgroundFetch = async () => {
      const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
      if (
        status === BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Restricted ||
        status === BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Denied
      ) {
        console.log("Background fetch is disabled");
        return;
      }

      const isTaskRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK);
      console.log("Task is registered:", isTaskRegistered);

      if (!isTaskRegistered) {
        await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_FETCH_TASK, {
          minimumInterval: 60 * 15,
          stopOnTerminate: false,
          startOnBoot: true,
        });

        console.log("Background fetch task registered");
      }
    };

    registerBackgroundFetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Tab One</Text>
      <View style={styles.separator} />
      <Button
        title="Display Notification"
        onPress={() => sendNotification()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" },
  title: { fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" },
  separator: { marginVertical: 30, height: 1, width: "80%" },
});

What works:
The background task registers correctly.
The task runs as expected when manually triggered using development tools like Instruments on macOS.
What doesn't work:
The TaskManager.defineTask function does not trigger automatically in the background under normal conditions on iOS.
Questions:
What could be causing the TaskManager.defineTask not to trigger automatically in iOS?
